# How do I change the playback speed in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

On the iPhone I can speed up the playback of podcasts to 2x.
Is there a way to do the same in iTunes?

Comment: What platform are you on, Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 19):

This is not natively possible in the Mac version of iTunes (nor Windows for the matter). You don’t mention if you have OS X or Windows. If you have the former, you have two choices:

1) If the podcast is an MP3 file, you can convert the file to an AAC file in iTunes (with an extension of m4a.) and then change the extension to m4b; the file becomes an audiobook which can be played faster if I am not mistaken.

2) Another alternative is to hear it in Quicktime, which has speed controls: Right click the file in iTunes and choose "Show In Finder”. Option-click the file (right click) and select “Open With…”, select QuickTime. Once in Quicktime option-click the "Accelerate" button to change the playback speed.

[image: QuickTime]

Comment: How did you highlight the pause button and do the circle on the next/accelerate butotn on the image? It's brilliant! :D

Comment: @JFW Meet http://skitch.com/ for the “circle/arrow/text”. The Highlight is a courtesy of Apple Inc. that decided to add that feature automatically on Quicktime X ;)

Comment: I now tried both methods. For the audiobook I didn't find a way to play it faster. The solution with Quicktime works but it seems to be even faster than 2x.

Comment: Hold Option and click Accelerate to get 1.1x, 1.2x, 1.3x, ... Intuitive really!

Answer (score 3):

There is a Mac menubar app, that allows you to change the playback speed in iTunes. http://wetfish.de/

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was (windows 7 not sure how it would work on mac) copy and paste the podcast from itunes into my doccuments and then open the podcast in VLC (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) i assume there is a download for Mac as well. VLC has speed controls and plays every type of file as far as im aware. Under the playback options it has a speed setting.

NB VLC also good for vidoes with out of sync A/V as has sync settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com) or Windows Media Player and the Chronotron plugin to change tempo or pitch.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add a little detail to this? Where can we get the plugin and how can we use it to change pitch? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Soundforge nits free and it will change tempo without changing pitch. It works well.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail (e.g. a link for that tool)? Seems Google is not my friend here as it only brings up a tool that is not free.

Comment: Yes, please add more detail to your answer.

Comment: I think they meant it's a free trial... that or they downloaded a warez hacked version on torrents.